# \NewEnviron for custom-scaled align* environment fails to compile with any ampersands (&)

Tags: math-mode, formatting, align, environments, fontsize

I want to increase only the text size of equation environments. I found this on another post:

```
\NewEnviron{myalign}{%
    \begin{align*}
    \scalebox{1.5}{$\BODY$}
    \end{align*}
}
```

It seems to work, but I when I include any `&` at all, it fails to compile e.g.

```
\begin{align}
    x &= 3
\end{align}
```

works, but not

```
\begin{myalign}
   x &= 3
\end{myalign}
```

Comment: What is the intent here? Do you have surrounding content before/after the `align`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll also see that

```
\begin{align*}
  \scalebox{1.5}{$x &= 3$}
\end{align*}
```

fails, which is exactly what your `myalign` is producing. It's not the problem with really with your `\NewEnviron`, but your interpretation of how you want to scale things. Specifically, that you can't let a group opening and closing straddle a `&`.

From your definition it seems like you want to enlarge the display of the `align` by 50%. Rather use a definition like this:

```
\NewEnviron{myalign}{%
  \Large\begin{align*}
    \BODY
  \end{align*}}
```

or (without [`environ`](//ctan.org/pkg/environ) and an up-to-date LaTeX)

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{myalign}{ b }{%
  \Large\begin{align*}
    #1
  \end{align*}
}{}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myalign}{ b }{%
  \Large\begin{align*}
    #1
  \end{align*}
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d
\end{align*}

{\Large
\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d
\end{align*}
}

\begin{myalign}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
  g(x) &= ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d
\end{myalign}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, you shouldn't use `align` for single equations, but just for multiple line alignments. It's possible that the author of that code liked to use `align` as a substitute for `equation`.

But that code cannot work with multiple lines: you need to apply the scaling to the whole `align` (but in the `aligned` form).

The following solution doesn't mean that I find the idea of scaling display particularly attractive (understatement for “I find it really ugly”).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{scaledisplay}{O{1.5}mb}
 {
  \begin{equation*}
  \scalebox{#1}{$\antintin_scaledisplay:nn { #2 } { #3 }$}
  \end{equation*}
 }
 {\ignorespacesafterend}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \antintin_scaledisplay:nn
 {
  \__antintin_scaledisplay_begin:n { #1 }
  #2
  \__antintin_scaledisplay_end:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__antintin_scaledisplay_begin:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {equation}{\displaystyle}
    {alignat}{\begin{alignedat}{-1}}
    {flalign}{\begin{aligned}}
   }
   {\begin{#1ed}}
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__antintin_scaledisplay_end:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {equation}{}
    {alignat}{\end{alignedat}}
    {flalign}{\end{aligned}}
   }
   {\end{#1ed}}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{scaledisplay}[2]{equation}
A=B
\end{scaledisplay}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\begin{scaledisplay}{align}
a&=b \\
cc&=ddd
\end{scaledisplay}
\lipsum[3][1-4]
\begin{scaledisplay}{alignat}
a&=b    &\quad uuu&=v \\
cc&=ddd &\quad u&=v
\end{scaledisplay}
\lipsum[4][1-4]
\begin{scaledisplay}{gather}
a=b \\
cc=dd
\end{scaledisplay}
\lipsum[5][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using font size changes rather than scaling (this also respects `fleqn`).

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{scaledisplay}{O{\Large}m}
 {
  \begin{equation*}
  \begin{minipage}{\displaywidth}
  #1
  \legacy_if:nTF { @fleqn } { \setlength{\leftskip}{\mathindent} } { \centering }
  $
  \__antintin_scaledisplay_begin:n { #2 }
 }
 {
  \__antintin_scaledisplay_end:n { #2 }
  $
  \end{minipage}
  \end{equation*}
  \ignorespacesafterend
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \antintin_scaledisplay:nn
 {
  \__antintin_scaledisplay_begin:n { #1 }
  #2
  \__antintin_scaledisplay_end:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__antintin_scaledisplay_begin:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {equation}{\displaystyle}
    {alignat}{\begin{alignedat}{-1}}
    {flalign}{\begin{aligned}}
   }
   {\begin{#1ed}}
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__antintin_scaledisplay_end:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {equation}{}
    {alignat}{\end{alignedat}}
    {flalign}{\end{aligned}}
   }
   {\end{#1ed}}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{scaledisplay}[\LARGE]{equation}
A=B
\end{scaledisplay}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\begin{scaledisplay}{align}
a&=b \\
cc&=ddd
\end{scaledisplay}
\lipsum[3][1-4]
\begin{scaledisplay}{alignat}
a&=b    &\quad uuu&=v \\
cc&=ddd &\quad u&=v
\end{scaledisplay}
\lipsum[4][1-4]
\begin{scaledisplay}{gather}
a=b \\
cc=dd
\end{scaledisplay}
\lipsum[5][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the `fleqn` option

[image]